# iOS: Is there a way to know if user has opted out of notifications?

Tags: ios, permissions, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

With `CLAuthorizationStatus` I can know exactly whether the user has denied the app permissions (`kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied`) or if the status is undetermined (`kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`).

... So is there something similar for notification services? I can't seem to find anything and there seems to be no way to differentiate between a user who has denied permissions and a user that just hasn't been shown the permissions popup yet.

Comment: Having the same problem.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]` returns 0 or none when the app is newly installed. Can't distinguish between "Not Prompted Yet" or "Denied"

Answer (score -1):

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *current = [[UIApplication   sharedApplication]currentUserNotificationSettings];
    if (current.types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone){
        NSLog(@"Notifications Enabled ios 8");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Notifications not Enabled ios 8");
    }

} else {
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    if (types != UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)
    {
        NSLog(@"Notifications Enabled");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Notifications not Enabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: This code cannot distinguish between the case when the user has not be prompted yet and when he/she has been prompted and denied it. So it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *currentSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
```

This code will give the most current settings related to notifications.

Comment: This code cannot distinguish between the case when the user has not be prompted yet and when he/she has been prompted and denied it. So it doesn't answer the question.